# Resolution stuck 1024x768 VirtualBox 6 VboxSVGA driver on guest Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, display-resolution

Just upgraded to VirtualBox 6 running on a Windows 10 host and swapped to the SVGA driver (which according to the docs is the new default). Guest is Lubuntu 18.04.

I cannot for the life of me make the resolution increase. I've purged and re-installed Guest Additions to no effect. (using VBoxLinuxAdditions.run uninstall, and re-running).

I've also tried the steps listed here: https://www.tecmint.com/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-ubuntu/

Rebooted several times between steps, but the resolution still restricted when using Monitor settings. xrandr lists just 3 resolutions, 640x480, 800x600 and 1024x768.

Any ideas?

Posted in VBox Forums too: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=91052

Comment: Hello, could you please specify a bit what you have tried so far? Where did you change resolution? What is the host of VirtualBox? Is Lubuntu the host machine or the virtual machine?

Comment: Sorry, updated now

Answer (score 3):

In VirtualBox, you have a menu that forces a user-specified screen resolution for the virtual screen. It should help you to specify Lubuntu the correct resolution:
[image: VirtualBox virtual screen resolution menu]

Comment: Greyed out using VboxSVGA. Switch to VMSVGA and all good. Guess the new driver isn't compatible yet

Comment: opposite- greyed out with (recommended) VMSVGA, all good w/ VboxSVGA

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where the video mode was stuck at 1024 on the GUI. I shut down the vm, reconfigured to VMSVGA, resized the window large to leave a hint, shutdown the vm, switched back to VBoxSVGA, quit VirtualBox then fired in terminal "VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/MaxGuestResolution 1920x1080" which "unstuck" things .. then rebooted VM all working fine now with Auto Resize and all.

Guest was Win 10 Pro 64, Host OSX, VBox 6.1.8 with 6.1.8 Additions. Posted here because I think its a niggly bug in VirtualBox and it seems to affect all combinations of guests and hosts sporadically. Hoping this helps out someone in the future as most related posts are very old and not about VBx6